# How to insert data from a select query using php

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, insert-into

I wan to insert data to mysql table from another database which is connected via ODBC.But I cannot enter into the while loop, here is my code - 
N.B: For security I dont provide db name, user and pass.
ODBC connection declared as 'connStr'

```
 <?php
    $connStr = odbc_connect("database","user","pass");
    $conn = mysqli_connect("server","user","pass","database");
    //$result_set=mysqli_query($conn,$datequery);
    //$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);

    echo "<br>";

    echo "<br>";

    $query="select cardnumber, peoplename, creditlimit, ROUND(cbalance,2) as cbalance, minpay from IVR_CardMember_Info
    where cardnumber not like '5127%'" ;


        $rs=odbc_exec($connStr,$query);
        $i = 1;
        while(odbc_fetch_row($rs))
        {   //echo "Test while";
            $cardnumber=odbc_result($rs, "cardnumber");
            $peoplename=odbc_result($rs, "peoplename");
            $creditlimit=odbc_result($rs, "creditlimit"); 
            $cbalance=odbc_result($rs, "cbalance"); 
            $minpay=odbc_result($rs, "minpay");


            $conn = mysqli_connect("server","user","pass","database");
            $sql= "INSERT INTO test_data(cardnumber, peoplename, creditlimit, cbalance, minpay) VALUES ('cardnumber', 'peoplename', 'creditlimit', 'cbalance', 'minpay') ";
            if(!(mysqli_query($conn,$sql))){
                //echo "Data Not Found";
                echo "<br>";

            }
            else{
                echo "Data Inserted"; 
                echo "<br>";
            }
            echo $i++ ;
        }

    echo "<br>";
odbc_close($connStr);

?>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: as a side note there is no need to repeat the mysqli connection inside the while loop. You already set it on top.

Comment: removed but still the same happens.

Comment: @Ashiq Can you put odbc_errormsg (connStr); after $connStr = odbc_connect("database","user","pass"); and post the result?

Comment: @Ashiq it is not meant to fix this issue but another that would cause your MySQL server to crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to understand why you can't enter `while() {...}`, you need to consider the following.

First, your call to [odbc_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php), which expects database source name, username and password for first, second and third parameter. It should be something like this (DSN-less connection):

```
<?php
...
$connStr = odbc_connect("Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Driver};Server=server;Database=database;", "user", "pass");
if (!$connStr) {
    echo 'Connection error';
    exit;
}
...
?>
```

Second, check for errors after [odbc_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php):

```
<?php
...
$rs = odbc_exec($connStr, $query);
if (!$rs) {
    echo 'Exec error';
    exit;
}
...
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it with just SQL check it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp), like:

```
     INSERT INTO test_data(cardnumber, peoplename, creditlimit, cbalance, minpay) 
     SELECT cardnumber, peoplename, creditlimit, 
     ROUND(cbalance,2) as cbalance, minpay from IVR_CardMember_Info
     where cardnumber not like '5127%'
```

Comment: the two tables (source and target) are on  two different databases and on different connections so the "single query" approach will never work